# Trouble testing via maven

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I made project, which build success via ant, but when I trying do it via maven I get 
Test in errors:
   initializationError(test.JdbcRoleDaoTest)
all my resources,which I use, are in src/main(test)/resources.
there are: schema.sql, db.properties and dir "datasets" with *.sql for testing databases.

Help, please!

mvn install -DskipTests
installing successful

```
public class TestJdbcRoleDao extends DatabaseTestCase {
private static final String SCHEMA = "./schema.sql";
private static boolean mustInit = true;
private static String url;
private static String driver;
private static String login;
private static String password;
private JdbcRoleDao jdbcRoleDao = null;
private Role tempRole = null;
private Connection jdbcConnection = null;
private IDataSet dbSet = null;
private IDataSet expectDataSet = null;
private ITable actualTable = null;
private ITable expectedTable = null;
private ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();;

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    jdbcRoleDao = new JdbcRoleDao();
    tempRole = new Role();
    Class.forName(driver);
    jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
}

@Test
public void testCreate() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException,
        DatabaseUnitException, IOException {
    tempRole.setId(4l);
    tempRole.setName("temp");
    jdbcRoleDao.create(tempRole);
    expectDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(classLoader
            .getResourceAsStream("datasets/createRole.xml"));
    expectedTable = expectDataSet.getTable("ROLE");
    dbSet = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection).createDataSet();
    actualTable = dbSet.getTable("ROLE");
    Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTable, actualTable);
}
```

....................... There is part of test class.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>DBProjects</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenDB</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MavenDB</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.181</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                <sourceEncoding>utf-8</sourceEncoding>
                <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/generated-classes/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: We are not psychics here. You need to provide more information on how your project is structured, what your scripts are like, what they do, what you want them to do. You can't expect any help, unless you're able to describe your actual problem. Better yet, you might even solve it yourself, if you take the time to explain it as you might get an idea of what the problem really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to made your project with

> mvn install -DskipTests

and see if it builds without others problems like dependency or others.

If it builds without problems, try to check dependency scopes

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html